# iPod touch 3rd-gen won't play videos in Safari

Tags: iphone, ipod

My iPod touch 3rd-gen won't play videos in Safari. It shows a play button with a line crossing it.

It used to play but now there's this problem.

What can I do?

Comment: Can you add a link to one of the videos causing the problem?

Answer (score 2):

THat circle with a line cross through it means that the format is not supported on the iPod Touch, or any other iOS device.

It is usually related to flash video's.
If you are looking at a youtube video go check out [m.youtube.com](http://m.youtube.com). It should load most videos to play just fine.

However if the source of your video is not a youtube (or other big site) then you may be out of luck.